# Do sites often use the same backend API for a public API aswell?

Tags: web-services, api, rest

Is it a common practise to use the same API to run a services main site as also offered as the public API or is it more common to develop them separate?

In theory I cant see any reason for them not to be the same just perhaps with different authentication mechanisms and request limitations when accessed publicly.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing for sure but consider the following problems that may arise when using the same set of API

1. Authentication/authorization (mentioned by you)
2. Flexibility/maintainability (preserving backward compatibility)
3. Unnecessary overhead of public API protocols
4. Not every API operation can/has to be public. You end up with inconsistent API usage
5. Difference between user (public) model/domain and the one used internally.

That being said I don't believe any site uses their own public API internally (not eating their own dog food).

Answer (score 0):

The public API in most of my site that indeed limits possibilities and functions, does authentication, and then goes to the same internal code the rest uses. A lot easier to keep things consistent troughout, but *do* version a public api & deprecate features if needed.